# Copy content of a cmd.exe window in windows using perl

Tags: perl, cmd

Im trying to copy the content of cmd.exe to a text file using perl in windows. 
Is there any simple way to do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by the content of `cmd.exe`? Do you mean what it outputs when it runs, or the actual hex code of the program?

Comment: Do you mean the contents of the file `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`? The output of a program you launch with `cmd.exe`? Or screen scraping the contents of a `cmd.exe` console?

Comment: Yes! the output of the cmd.exe after it si executed. But I dont want to use the "> textFil.txt" I need a perl script to do this job. Is it possible to copy the text and write in a file ?

Answer (score 1):

```
my $text = `cmd.exe params`;
open my $fh, '>>', 'exec.log';
print $fh $text;
close $fh;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
system("command args > log");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with windows much, but I would imagine that it is the same as getting output from a linux executable.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
# Using strawberry perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $cmd = 'c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /?|';
open ( FH, $cmd ) or die "Can't open $cmd: $!";
my $content = do { local $/; <FH>; };
print $content;
```

Comment: I wanted to copy the conent of a cmd.exe that is already running and is executing a task on it (say qwerty.exe) which is already running in the system.

Comment: What you can probably do in this case is use the TEE command to dump the output to a log file while it continues to display on the console, and then use perl to read from that log file.  Read more on the tee command here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29

Answer (score 0):

You've executed a task in a Console window and now you need to copy those lines? I'm not sure there's a way to do that.

If you haven't already done that, you can use [Win32::Console](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-Console-0.09/Console.pm) to create a console window, and read and write to that console window.